# Should Tag Synonyms require Moderator Approval As well as a Rating of 4?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, moderators, tags

As an aside, I notice there's a tag named, "tag" which is not a synonym of, "tags." I would suggest making it a synonym via the site-feature I just got as a privilege... but I can't.

Right now, there's an absurdly convoluted means of suggesting tag synonyms, for fear of an equally convoluted means of undoing them. This seems ridiculous.... When I looked for a topic like this one, I found a string of people suggesting via meta this or that tag synonym to moderators... instead of using the in-site mechanic.

From what I've read, everyone agrees it's absurd, but this is the best we can do with a poorly designed system. But... since we have to throw the tags at the moderators anyway, why not just make them part of the system?

As HDE 226868 mentioned in one topic, it's honestly too dangerous, where a few users could accidentally screw up major tags without meaning to. So, if possible, we really ought to make moderator approval necessary, since that's already the defacto system?

Comment: I believe this question should be asked in the main meta. Even if people agree in the change, if the question is posted only here nothing will be done.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Nothing can be done here? Fair enough.

Comment: @johny Worldbuilsing.se policies can be agreed upon here. But changes to the programming of SE will only be acted upon if proposed in meta.stackexchange.com (and if the devs agree with it).

Comment: @JBH Can you migrate it there? It's possible that would be best.

Comment: Duh... brain fart. I retracted the close vote. I flagged the question for the Mods with a comment that it should be migrated to [meta.se]. I forgot the VTC process doesn't uniquely flag the mods, but the flagging process does.